# selenium chromedriver php detected as a bot

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, screen-scraping

Just wondering if anyone can porvide any insight to a problem that I am having. I am trying to scrape a site using selenium and chromedriver. The site seems to always detect the chromedriver browswer as a bot. here is my configuration, how can I avoid this detection?

Selenium build info

Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-108-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'

I am using ChromeDriver 2.33.506092. Any help is appreciated

```
<?php
    // An example of using php-webdriver.
    namespace Facebook\WebDriver;
    use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
    use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
    use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) .'/vendor/autoload.php';

$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36';


$host = 'http://localhost:4321/wd/hub';
$url = $host;
$options = new ChromeOptions();
// Setting the binary is optional.
//$options->setBinary('/bin/chromedriver');

// Available options:
// http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
$options->addArguments(array(
    //'--window-size=571,428',
  // '--start-maximized',
//  '--headless',
    "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1080", "--no-sandbox",
    '--user-agent=' . $userAgent,
    "disable-infobars"

));



// Setting extensions is also optional
//$options->addExtensions(array(
//    '/path/to/chrome/extension1.crx',
//    '/path/to/chrome/extension2.crx',
//));

$caps = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$caps->setPlatform('WINDOWS');
$caps->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);

$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($url, $caps,5000);



$driver->manage()->deleteAllCookies();
$url2 = 'https://www.realtor.ca/Residential/Map.aspx#CultureId=1&ApplicationId=1&RecordsPerPage=9&MaximumResults=9&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&StoreyRange=0-0&BedRange=0-0&BathRange=0-0&LongitudeMin=-156.0498046875&LongitudeMax=-16.9189453125&LatitudeMin=34.88592973581311&LatitudeMax=72.71190267150946&SortOrder=A&SortBy=1&viewState=m&ZoomLevel=4&PropertyTypeGroupID=1';

$driver->get($url2);
sleep(20)  ;
$cookies = $driver->manage()->getCookies();
```